# I'm beginner in android...I'm not sure how to access string values within a JSONArray. My json is look like these

Tags: json

{
     "status":1,
     "message":"City Listed !",
     "cityData":["Pune","Banglore","Mumbai"]
}

I'm getting status and message value bt cityData is []...how can i fetch the value of Array.

My code is :-

ArrayList jsonArrayString = new ArrayList();

```
            JSONArray cityData = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
            Log.v("cityData", String.valueOf(cityData));
            List<JSONObject> list=new ArrayList();
            for(int i=0;i<cityData.length();i++)
            {
                //list.add(cityData.getString(i));
                list.add(cityData.getJSONObject(i++));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String jsonString = "{ \"status\":1, \"message\":\"City Listed !\", \"cityData\":[\"Pune\",\"Banglore\",\"Mumbai\"] }";
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
        JSONArray city = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cityData");
        for (Object s : city) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example to access Status

```
 var status=[];
    $.each(jsonArrayString,function(i,v)
    status.push(this.status);
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

define class for your json object

```
public class jsonObj{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string[] status { get; set; }
}
```

then use code to deserialize:

```
    String jsonString = "{ \"status\":1, \"message\":\"City Listed !\", \"cityData\":[\"Pune\",\"Banglore\",\"Mumbai\"] }";
   jsonObj myJSON = System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<jsonObj>();
```